# ConTeXt: How to adjust the space before and after a section with respect to gridset

Tags: spacing, sectioning, context, sections-paragraphs, grid-typesetting

I use

```
grid=yes
```

in my setuplayout. With `\showgrid` I can see, that the space before and after a section is the same as before and after a subsection (3 lines before, and 2 lines after). But it would be nicer, if the subsection-title empty-space would be 2 lines before, and 1 line after, there should be a significant difference between the space around section and the space around subsection. This is possible with respect to grid=yes, indicated by the shown lines, but how?

Comment: ``\setuphead[subsection][before={\blank[line]},style=bold]`` (also: [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/14066) needed)

Comment: Thank you. And how can I adjust the space after a section with respect to grid? To be honest, I dont understand what \blank[line] does, after reading the article \blank in the wiki.

Comment: One additional question to your comment:
 
\setuphead[subsection][before={\blank[line]},style=bold]

If I add that in my environment, which is loaded is the main file, than it has noe effect. But if I add that directly in the mainfile (that one with \starttext \stoptext), than it works, why?

Comment: 1. ``[after={\blank[...]}]``. 2. It inserts a vertical blank of the size of a line. 3. Try [this solution](http://www.ntg.nl/pipermail/ntg-context/2010/047980.html).

Comment: @Mustafa: I have tried to improve the wiki article on [\blank](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Command/blank). Is it understandable now? If it is not, can you tell me what questions it does not answer clearly, so I can make it better?

Comment: Without a full example, I don't think this can be answered. Please edit in a MWE and request reopening.